# Error on compiling gwt project on ant but not in eclipse

Tags: java, gwt, ant

I'm trying to compile a `gwt` project with ant, and I get the error cannot find symbol on `MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase(DBUtils.getDatabase());`

If I compile it with the gwt plugin in eclipse everything works fine.
See image below:

[image]

Comment: You're missing a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Def missing a dependency.

I would strongly suggest to use Maven over Ant. It has a steep learning curve, but once you are there you are going to love it.

In order to make your life easier I would suggest you to start with the [GWT archetype project](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html). It's a GWT maven project already configured and ready to go, a very good base to start learning.